# Grouping many columns in one column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that is similar to this one:

```
|   | id | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
|---|----|--------|--------|--------|
| 0 | 22 | A      | B      | C      |
| 1 | 23 | B      | C      | D      |
| 2 | 24 | C      | B      | A      |
| 3 | 25 | D      | A      | C      |
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
|   | Group | id_count |
|---|-------|----------|
| 0 | A     |        3 |
| 1 | B     |        3 |
| 2 | C     |        3 |
| 3 | D     |        2 |
```

Basically for each group I want to know how many *people(id)* have chosen it.

I know there is `pd.groupby()`, but it only gives an appropriate result for one column (if I give it a list, it does not combine group 1,2,3 in one column).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt('id', value_name='Group')
         .groupby('Group')
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='id_count'))

print (df1)
  Group  id_count
0     A         3
1     B         3
2     C         4
3     D         2
```